# How to assign the values to a text box fields which are in dynamically generated matrix in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a dynamic matrix with Angular JS, in each cell of matrix there is a input text box, I am able to generate the dynamic names of ng-model for every text box fields. But I want to fill the values of each input box according to the option selected in select box. On ng-change I have called a function to update the input boxes but I am strucked in assigning the values to them because of dynamic ng-model names. Please see my Html:

```
     <table id="hq-matrix-table" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr class="column-label">
                <td>#</td>
                <td ng-repeat="column in columns">[[column]]</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody class="price-matrix-table">
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">

                <td class="row-label">[[row]]</td>

                <td ng-repeat="column in columns" >

                    <div class="input-group" ng-hide="column == '0' && row =='0'">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>

                       <input ng-model="cells[[row +''+ column]]" id="cell.[[ row ]]_[[column ]]"  ng-class="myVar" ng-click ="myVar='input-matrix'"  placeholder="No Price" type="text" class="form-control" />


                    </div>

                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>

        </table>
```

and on select box change

```
    <select ng-change="updateMatrixCells(section.costPerOption, [[section.id]] )" id="select[[section.id]]"  name="costPerOption" ng-model="section.costPerOption" id="costPerOption" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" onchange="$(this).selectpicker('refresh');">
 <option ng-repeat="cost in readyCosts" value="[[ cost.value ]]" >[[ cost.name ]]</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use row $index and column $index to get the exact cell to update

```
<input ng-model="cells[$parent.$index][$index]" ng-class="myVar" 
ng-click ="myVar='input-matrix'"  placeholder="No Price" 
type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: I have already manage to give the ng-model a dynamic value like <input ng-model="cells[[row +''+ column]]" /> but I am not able to assign them the values through controller. Using $scope.cells.

Comment: Didn't understood the problem related to select box

Comment: actually what i need is, the values of textbox will changes according to select box values. As you can see in above code I have created a select box field, and on change of that field i have to change the textbox values.

Comment: function call on ng-change of select box and i am passing the value of selected option.